# Importing excel file using php inserting blank rows with auto increment id in database

Tags: php, import

I have  1 row csv file .When I click on import button  1 row is inserted in database table with auto increment id and date(column name) value 0000-00-00,  but no values in the other columns.

```
 <?php

        if (isset($_POST["import"])) {

            ini_set('max_execution_time', 120); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

            //$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            //$ext=substr($file,strrpos($file,"."),(strlen($file)-strrpos($file,".")));
            //if($ext=="csv")

          $handle = fopen($file, "r");
          //$c = 0;
          while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle,",")) !== false)
                    {


          $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[0]);
         $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[1]);
          $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[2]);
           $url =mysqli_real_escape_string( $filesop[3]);
           $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[4]);

            $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[5]);
            //print_r($filesop);



          $sql = "insert into report(category,tags,title,url,description,date) values ('$category','$tags','$title','$url','$description','$date')";
        //$c = $c + 1;
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
         //echo $sql;

        // echo $filesop[0];
         //echo $filesop[1];

          //echo "success";
           exit();

                    }
        //if($result){
        echo " upload success";



           //ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',FALSE);
          // fclose($handle);


        // }

         //else
        // echo "cannot upload csv file";   



        }

            mysqli_close($conn);        
        ?>
```

my csv file(values of 1 row)

```
Marketing & Customer Analytics,Trends & Product Updates,Segment Launches Segment Select,https://martechseries.com/analytics/customer-data-platforms/segment-launches-segment-select-new-program-help-companies-leverage-first-party-data-certified-partners/,"Segment, the customer data infrastructure company, launched Segment Select, a new program designed to help Channel and Technology Partners easily build and implement solutions for their customers that leverage Segment’s Customer Data Infrastructure (CDI).",2/24/2019
```

I have id,category,tags ,title,url,description,date columns in my database table.

Comment: Check Colum Empty or not Using  if(!empty($category)){  proccess insert query  }

Comment: what do you get if you var_dump($filesop)

Comment: nothing is displayed on the  screen for var_dump($filesop);

Comment: var_dump($filesop); returns null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import excel in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095784/import-excel-in-php)