# import excel in php

Tags: php, csv

values are not mapping in database table columns

**this is my code**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["import"])) {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 120); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

    //$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    //$ext=substr($file,strrpos($file,"."),(strlen($file)-strrpos($file,".")));
    //if($ext=="csv")

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    //$c = 0;

    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle,",")) !== false)
    {
        $category    = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[0]);
        $tags        = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[1]);
        $title       = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[2]);
        $url         = mysqli_real_escape_string( $filesop[3]);
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[4]);
        $date        = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[5]);
        //print_r($filesop);

        var_dump($filesop);
        //echo $filesop[0];

        $sql = "insert into report(category,tags,title,url,description,date) values ('$category','$tags','$title','$url','$description','$date')";
        //$c = $c + 1;
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

        //echo $sql;
        //echo $filesop[1];

        //echo "success";
        exit();
    }

    //if($result){
        //echo " upload success";

        //ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',FALSE);

        fclose($handle);
    // }

    //else
        // echo "cannot upload csv file";   
}

mysqli_close($conn);        
?>
```

**returns null in my output screen**

```
var_dump($filesop);
```

**my database sample screen shot**

[image: my database sample screen shot]

**my csv file**

```
Marketing & Customer Analytics,Trends & Product Updates,Segment Launches Segment Select,https://martechseries.com/analytics/customer-data-platforms/segment-launches-segment-select-new-program-help-companies-leverage-first-party-data-certified-partners/,"Segment, the customer data infrastructure company, launched Segment Select, a new program designed to help Channel and Technology Partners easily build and implement solutions for their customers that leverage Segment’s Customer Data Infrastructure (CDI).",2/24/2019
```

Comment: What is the error are you facing? show data of excel file

Comment: I am having  id(autoincrement)  and date value 0000-00-00  in my table,other columns remaining empty  after importing.

Comment: i recommend you print your array first and see what keys are attached to each of your rows.
right after your `while` statement use this:

`echo '<pre>';`

`print_r($your_array);`

`echo '</pre>'`;

`die();`


the `'<pre>';` will make your array look pretty so you can read trough it.
and use a library(you are asking for excel import and your are using csv import here)

use this(not hard to use it)

[https://github.com/akeneo-labs/spreadsheet-parser]

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you missed parameters in [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function. You need to pass the database object in `mysqli_real_escape_string` function. 
 Like example :

**Your code :** `$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($filesop[0]);`

**New code** : `$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[0]);`

also helpful code below please check it.

```
while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle,",")) !== false)
{
    $category    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $filesop[0]);
    $tags        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $filesop[1]);
    $title       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $filesop[2]);
    $url         = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $filesop[3]);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $filesop[4]);
    $date        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $filesop[5]);
    $sql = "insert into report(category,tags,title,url,description,date) values ('$category','$tags','$title','$url','$description','$date')";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I have tried .but it is not working.var_dump($filesop);  returns null.

Comment: What is an error there? Please add this code on top of your script for check error. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>D:\xamppp\htdocs\rev\lumino\importexcel.php</b> on line <b>196</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in <b>D:\xamppp\htdocs\rev\lumino\importexcel.php</b> on line <b>200</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>D:\xamppp\htdocs\rev\lumino\importexcel.php</b> on line <b>202</b><br />
I got these errors

Comment: Please show you your file upload code or add file upload code in your question so it will easy to giving the proper answer.